# How to get parent path of %CD%

Tags: batch-file, dos

How do I get the parent path of the current %CD%.

For instance:

```
ECHO %CD%
```

result: `C:\Windows\System32`

(This does not work)

```
ECHO %CD%..\
```

**desired result:** `C:\Windows`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try changing the current directory and then using `%cd%`:

```
pushd ..
echo %cd%
popd
```