# cmd: Open explorer window of folder if not already open

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

This will open MyFolder in Explorer

```
explorer "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\MyFolder"
```

I'd like it to **only** do this if it **isn't already opened**.
Otherwise the the folder gets opened multiple times

This is for windows cmd batch

Thanks

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836825/how-to-check-if-explorer-window-is-open-by-title-in-batch) helps.

Answer (score 5):

If the path doesn't need quotes:
`start C:\Users\Username\Desktop\MyFolder`

If the path does need quotes:
`start "" "C:\program files"`

Answer (score 1):

Check the [listWindows.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/listWindows.bat) (unfortunately I think tasklist does not handle the window titles of the explorer.exe windows). It will list all opened windows and the name of the executable they belong to.The windows that are opened by the explorer will have the folder name as a title (only the name - without the whole path) so you can try this:

```
call listWindows.bat|find /i "explorer::MyFolder" >nul 2>&1 || (
   explorer "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\MyFolder"
)
```