# Windows batch script to determine last folder in list of paths

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to read a list of paths from a file and determine each time the last folder. I have found [something to start with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280969/windows-batch-loop-over-folder-string-and-parse-out-last-folder-name), failed, read various threads dealing with nested for loops and variable expansions however without success. I do not get a "Last folder:" response.
Anyone seeing the problem here? Any help is greatly appreciated!

External file (paths.txt):

```
C:\FirstFolder\NextFolder\LastFolder
C:\Somewhere\Deeper\FinallyThere
C:\Temp
```

Windows batch script:

```
@echo OFF
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=* eol=#" %%f in (%CD%\paths.txt) do (
    echo Get new path from file: %%f
    set mydir=%%f
    set m=%mydir:\=;%
    call :GET_SYMLINK %%m
)

setLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
goto :eof


:GET_SYMLINK
for /F "tokens=* delims=;" %%i IN (%1) DO call :LAST_FOLDER %%i
goto :eof


:LAST_FOLDER
if "%1"=="" (
    echo Last folder: %LAST%
    goto :eof
)
set LAST=%1
SHIFT
goto :LAST_FOLDER
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you are not clear about what is the result you want, but if it is this:

```
LastFolder
FinallyThere
Temp
```

... then this Batch file got it:

```
@echo off
for /F %%a in (paths.txt) do echo %%~Na
```

For further details, type `for /?` and read the description about "FOR variable modifiers".

If the paths may have spaces, include "delims=" option in FOR this way:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in (paths.txt) do echo %%~Na
```

Comment: Excellent, that's what I effectively needed, tried that approach at the beginning but couldn't figure out the %%~Na. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo OFF
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=* eol=#" %%f in (%CD%\paths.txt) do (
    echo Get new path from file: %%f
    set mydir=%%f
)
set m=%mydir:\=;%
call :GET_SYMLINK %m%
```

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Hence, replacing the `%`s in the setting of `m` within the loop with `!` should fix the problem - in part.

Next `%%m` refers to the matavariable (loop-control variable) `m` - `%m%` refers to the environment variable `m` but within the loop to the **original** value, `!m!` to the value as the loop changes.

Next problem is that since you are replacing `\` with `;` and `;` is a separator, to pass it as a parameter to your subroutine, you would need to "enclose it in double quotes." You could then remove those double-quotes by using `%~1` in your subroutine if that is what you require.

Personally, I'd move the substringing to the subroutine, since `mydir` would then contain the line. Since you say you want the last line from the file, then at the end of the loop, `mydir` will contain the last line, so there's no point in doing the subroutine for each line - just once at the end is sufficient.

I'm not sure what your subroutines are intended to do, so I'll make no comment about those.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, wasn't aware abou the block statement and effectively lost myself in the variable type jungle. As the the oneliner of @Aacini does the job I'll give him the credits.