# Trying to get the last token in a file string but getting delimiter=\" was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

I'm not sure what is going wrong. I've been trying to follow code examples that I've found from other's that were asking a question along what I'm trying to do, and even have followed what the answers have said, and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
SET mypath=%~dp0
SET mypath=%mypath:~0,-1%

echo Selected Text file = %mypath%
SET STRING=%mypath%
echo %STRING%
pause
FOR /f "tokens=3* delimiters=\" %%i in ("%STRING%") do (
SET VAR= %%i
echo %%i
echo %VAR%
)
pause
```

the error that I get is that delimiters=\" was unexpected at this time.

Comment: You are misspelling it.

Comment: Type `for /?` in command prompt to see the correct syntax/spelling of the option keywords...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

batch scripting language is not exactly the Shakespere's language

```
FOR /f "tokens=3* delims=\" %%i in ("%STRING%") do (
```

And as  Dennis van Gils mentioned in the comments you need [delayed expansion:](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
SET mypath=%~dp0
SET mypath=%mypath:~0,-1%

echo Selected Text file = %mypath%
SET STRING=%mypath%
echo %STRING%
pause
FOR /f "tokens=3* delims=\" %%i in ("%STRING%") do (
  SET VAR=%%i
  echo %%i
  echo !VAR!
)
pause
```

Comment: You should maybe mention that his echo still won't work because of delayed Expansion

Comment: @DennisvanGils - yep.One moment please. I have a pancake in the pan and it's not smelling good...

Comment: Ok. I wasn't sure if delayed expansion was needed or not based on the examples that I looked up of this on stackoverflow (specifically this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280969/windows-batch-loop-over-folder-string-and-parse-out-last-folder-name)

Comment: Still getting that delimiter=\" was unexpected at this time. error. :S

Comment: @ThomasMorse - try now.Forgot to delete `iter` from the second excerpt.

Comment: @npocmaka and, how did the pancake turn out?

Comment: @npocmaka A moment of silence for our fallen brother (`press any key to continue . . .`)