# How to know upper folder name via cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

is there any way to know what is the name of upper folder(directory) via cmd in windows? for example you are in C:\A\B\C I need a command which tells B

Comment: This link may help you ... [Get parent folder name using batch file.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280969/windows-batch-loop-over-folder-string-and-parse-out-last-folder-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is -- use [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) loops:

```bat
set "FOLDER=C:\A\B\C"

for %%J in ("%FOLDER%") do for %%I in ("%%~dpJ.") do echo(%%~nxI
```

The outer loop is needed to go up one level as `%%~dpJ` expands to `C:\A\B\`; let us append a `.` like `%%~dpJ.` to get `C:\A\B\.`, which is equivalent to `C:\A\B`; finally, the inner loop is needed to retrieve the pure name of the referenced directory as `%%~nxI` returns `B`.

---

It is also possible using one `for` loop:

```bat
set "FOLDER=C:\A\B\C"

for %%I in ("%FOLDER%\..") do echo(%%~nxI
```

The `..` means one level up, and `C:\A\B\C\..` is therefore equivapent to `C:\A\B`; finally, `%%~nxI` returns `B` again.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative, using the built in %CD% variable.

From the command prompt:

```dos
For %A In ("%CD%\..\.") Do @Echo(%~nxA
```

From a batch file:

```dos
@For %%A In ("%CD%\..\.") Do @(Echo(%%~nxA&Timeout 5 1>Nul)
```